# How to utilize the Instagram API with in Flask framework?

Tags: python

So I'm trying to make a simple app using the Flask framework and the [Instagram API](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram).

I have my application set up and everything is working well. But how can I import the Instagram module in my application?

I have run the `$ pip install python-instagram`, but when I try to import the module into my script I get the `ImportError: No module named instagram`

So how can I utilize the Instagram Python API in Flask?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I followed [this](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) tutorial to set up Flask on my computer. It's running on virtualenv on folder on my computer. When I installed the Instagram Python API it was put in a folder `/build` inside my app which looks like this:

```
instapp/
-- app/
   -- __init__.py
   -- static
   -- templates
   -- views.py

-- build/
   -- httplib2/
   -- python-instagram/
   -- simplejson/

-- flask/
   -- bin/
   -- include/
   -- lib/

-- run.py
-- tmp
-- virtualenv.py
```

Comment: Obviously the module is not in the right place. People here cannot really help you with that issue without having much more information about your setup.

Comment: Thanks, added an update to the question.

Comment: When you install instagram you have to use the `pip` from the virtualenv (i.e. `flask/bin/pip`), not the global `pip`. When I try that here I get everything installed in `flask/lib/...` which is the expected location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Miguel pointed out in the comments I used the `flask/bin/pip` instead of the global pip and everything worked fine! Thanks!